# Cordova: error while trying to build android app, says "Unsupported class file major version 63"

Tags: java, cordova, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem building this cordova app. When executed the command `cordova build`, on Android platform, the error says

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '...\platforms\android\settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file '...\platforms\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 63
```

I'm using gradle 7.6 and jdk 17.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Tried using gradle 8.0.2 with jdk 19, and same result. Throws the same error, and doesn't gets past there during the build process.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same error using Gradle 7.1.1 and managed to resolve it.

This post recommends using Java JDK 16 or older because Gradle does not support newer versions.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1412

> TL;DR; It's recommended to use Java 11.
>
> Java 18 isn't supported by Gradle which is one of the build tooling systems used by Android, and java projects in general.
>
> Cordova-android@10 uses gradle 7.1.1, so in terms of Gradle the maximum supported Java is Java 16.

Switching from Java JDK 19 to Java JDK 11.0.17 resolved the issue. Java JDK 16.0.2 did not work for me, it gave me another error.

You can get Java JDK 11 here: https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html

Comment: Yeah, I eventually figured out that reading the Cordova documentation stated that you need Java 11. And fixed that. But now, I cannot emulate my app with cordova emulate because it says that the path is correct, but my SDK doesn't has the \bin. So, now I'm stuck trying to fix that.